# Sublime minimap selection color

Tags: xml, themes, sublimetext2, sublimetext, color-scheme

I've been using an ugly selection color (cyan) as my color scheme's selection background color so that when I had highlight all instances of a term, I can easily find the others.

I'd much rather have a nice transparent/low contrast text selection background and set the minimap text selection background to a more opaque/higher contrast color.

Is this possible?

My theme.tmTheme file looks like this:

```
    <dict>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <!-- … -->
            <key>selection</key>
            <string>cyan</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Am hoping for something like `<key>minimapselection</key>`